# TextInputEditText height not updated after call View.updatePadding method

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have TextInputEditText inside a ConstraintLayout.
I use method `doOnTextChange` to change the right and bottom padding when text length is more that 20 symbols.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected until I move to the next fragment and return back. The **height** of view didn't update after call `updatePadding` method.

```
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/main_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/main_margin"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="#d8d8d8"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0.5dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="1dp"
            app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="@={comment}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Code to change the padding:

```
viewBinding.textInputEditText.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
    if (text?.length ?: 0 > 20){
        viewBinding.textInputEditText.updatePadding(right = 16.toPx(), bottom = 50.toPx())
    } else {
        viewBinding.textInputEditText.updatePadding(right = 60.toPx(), bottom = 12.toPx(), top = 16.toPx())
    }
}
```

How it works when screen starts:

[image: current behavior gif]

And how it works after moving to next fragment and go back:

[image: expected behavior gif]

Answer (score 0):

Please update padding on TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm updating padding of TextInputEditText, maybe it was not clearly described. Updated description to avoid misunderstanding.